# Identifying Zoom in/out level in MapKitView

Tags: objective-c, ios4

Thanks in advance.

Can you please let me know if there are any delegate methods that help us to identify the current zoom level when the user zooms in/out of a MapKitView?

-Sekhar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```